# Java 8 group by individual elements of list

Tags: java, java-stream

```
class Person {
    String personName;
    List<Skill> skills;
}

class Skill {
    String skillName;
}
```

How to obtain a map of

1. skillName and personName
2. skillName and person Object

E.g. John has skills painting, kungfu. James has cooking, karate, kungfu, Chris has painting, hiking

Output

```
painting -> John, Chris
kungfu -> John, James
cooking -> James
karate -> James
hiking -> Chris
```

What I have tried:

```
list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.skills.stream(), Collectors.toSet()))
```

I know this does not work, because you cannot group by e.skills.stream().

```
list.stream().flatMap(e -> e.skills.stream()).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.skillName, Collectors.toSet()));
```

It does group by skillName (but only Skill objects), however reference to Person is lost due to flatMap.

Answer (score 2):

I think this would be easier to accomplish if you first converted your `List<Person>` into a `Stream<PersonNameSkill>`, where `PersonNameSkill` represents a nominal tuple containing the `Person`'s name and a single `Skill` that is attributed to them.

In Java 14, you can take advantage of `record` to create this nominal tuple:

```
record PersonNameSkill(String personName, String skillName) {}
```

Now that this exists, you can write a solution (Java 8+):

```
list.stream().flatMap(person -> person.skills.stream()
        .map(skill -> new PersonNameSkill(person.personName, skill.skillName)))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(PersonNameSkill::skillName,
        Collectors.mapping(PersonNameSkill::personName, Collectors.toSet())));
```

---

If you're using an older version of Java, you can create `PersonNameSkill` with:

```
public class PersonNameSkill {
    private final String personName;
    private final String skillName;

    // Constructor, getters, equals, hashCode, etc.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this look good in Java 14. However given relatively simple nature of the question, I feel there should be simpler solution. Well, I'm no expert on streams or lambda calculus.

Comment: @sakura The simpler solution is to just not use a `Stream` for this ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯, but I answered with a `Stream` because your question is tagged with [tag:java-stream].

Comment: The  question is similar to computing back of the book index.

Comment: I'm not sure if my initial answer was clear, but this solution will work with Java 8+ if you replace the use of `record` with the `public class PersonNameSkill` I show at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: It would even work with an anonymous type, i.e. `list.stream().flatMap(person -> person.skills.stream() .map(skill -> new Object() { String personName = person.personName; String skillName = skill.skillName; }))) .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o -> o.skillName, Collectors.mapping(o -> o.personName, Collectors.toSet())));`

Answer (score 1):

You can create [Map.Entry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) object for every `Skill_name->Person_name` combination, and then use [Collectors.groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) for grouping the person names with skills

```
Map<String, List<String>> groupingBySkill = persons.stream()
            .flatMap(p -> p.getSkills().stream().map(Skill::getSkillName)
                    .map(sk -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, String>(sk, p.getPersonName())))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                    Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```